# For some reason, when I try to parent the mesh to my model's rig, it distorts the feet and hair

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm a beginner at Blender and this is the first model I've tried to rig. However, I've encountered a problem where the hair and feet become distorted when I parent the mesh to the rig.

I've gone to YouTube and Reddit for a way to fix this issue, but there's been nothing so far. If anyone here could offer any help or advice, I would really appreciate it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE. can you share ur file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Thank you, I shared my file like you asked.

Comment: Autoweights do not work well on non-manifold geometry.  First, fix non-manifold geometry: use select non manifold operation, disable "boundary" in operator panel.  All that gets selected has problems that need fixing.  "Boundary" is not a deal-breaker the way the rest is, but it will still break autoweights, and you need to paint manually.  I see no hair bones, so presumably your hair will need to be parented to your head-- you probably need to adjust the armature to match what you want to do with your model.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked into your file, and it seems there is an excess amount of both `Armature` modifiers on all your meshes, as well as way to many vertex groups. Removing all of them worked in my case.

(Note, I joined the meshes into one mesh, before removing all `Vertex groups`)

Comment: Hmm, I get autoweight failure when joining all meshes in that file.  Probably from all the non-manifold geometry.

Comment: Umm, thank you for the help, but I'm still left rather confused. When you say that you removed the Armature modifiers and the vertex groups, do you mean the all the excess or every single armature and vertex groups? Moreover, there's also something having to do with non-manifold geometry which I'm struggling to solve since I can't find the options that I need to solve it. I'm on version 3.6.1.0 of Blender if that helps.

Comment: I removed *all* vertex groups and armature modifiers, then parented the mesh to the armature with automatic weights. If you weightpainted already, maybe you should try only removing excess vertex groups.